# encountered issue when I used JoinWindows.ofTimeDifferenceWithNoGrace(Duration.ofHours(24)) for left join

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I encountered issue when I used JoinWindows.ofTimeDifferenceWithNoGrace(Duration.ofHours(24)) for left join

Should this method keep all the records in the left stream for 24 hours to find matching records in the right stream?

I noticed many records were emitted only a few hours after they were consumed into the left stream:

Here is my code:

```
public KStream<String, KafkaJobEvent> kStream(
        @Value("${input-topic}") final String inputTopic,
        final StreamsBuilder builder) {

    final KStream<String, KafkaJobEvent> sourceStream = builder.stream(inputTopic,
                    Consumed.with(Serdes.ByteArray(), Serdes.ByteArray())
                            .withTimestampExtractor(new DefaultTimestampExtractor(logReader)))
           .selectKey((k, v) -> v.getID); // re-key the stream 


    final Map<String, KStream<String, KafkaJobEvent>> branches = sourceStream.split(Named.as(SUB_STREAM))
            .branch((key, value) -> value.getTarget().contains("A"), Branched.as("A"))
            .branch((key, value) -> value.getTarget().contains("B"), Branched.as("B"))
            .defaultBranch();


    final KStream<String, KafkaJobEvent> streamA = branches.get(SUB_STREAM + "A");
    final KStream<String, KafkaJobEvent> streamB = branches.get(SUB_STREAM +"B");


    final Duration windowDuration = Duration.ofHours(24);

    return streamA
            .leftJoin(
                    streamB,
                    new ValueJoiner<KafkaJobEvent, KafkaJobEvent, KafkaJobEventJoinedValue>() {
                        @Override
                        public KafkaJobEventJoinedValue apply(final KafkaJobEvent left, final KafkaJobEvent right) {
                           
                           return KafkaJobEventJoinedValue.builder()
                                    .left(left)
                                    .right(right)
                                    .build();
                        }
                    },
                    JoinWindows.ofTimeDifferenceWithNoGrace(windowDuration),
                    StreamJoined.with(
                            Serdes.String(), // Key serde
                            kafkaJobEventSerde, // Left value serde
                            kafkaJobEventSerde  // Right value serde
                    ))
            .filter((key, value) -> value.getRight() == null)
            .mapValues(KafkaJobEventJoinedValue::getLeft)
            .process(() -> new ContextualProcessor<String, KafkaJobEvent, String, KafkaJobEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void process(final Record<String, KafkaJobEvent> record) {
                    try {
                        log.info("the timestamp:{} for record key:{}, record value:{}",
                                record.timestamp(), record.key(), record.value());
                       // do something ...
                    } catch (final Exception e) {
                        log.error("Exception found while handling message for record value:{}", record.value(), e);
                    }

                }
            });



}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Should this method keep all the records in the left stream for 24 hours to find matching records in the right stream?

Yes it does. And not just for the left stream, but also for the right stream.

> I noticed many records were emitted only a few hours after they were consumed into the left stream:

Well, if a left input record does not join yet, because no matching record arrived on the right hand side, nothing is emitted right away. Only if a left input record does not join at all within the 24h window, a `<key, <left,null>>` result would be emitted after 24h (your join window size, given that you don't use a grace period).

Left results cannot be emitted right away, because the left record might still join with a future right hand side record and emitting a left-join plus inner-join result would be incorrect.

Note, the 24h is "time difference" so the window looks into the past and future. If you want the left hand record to only join with older right hand side record, and emit a left-join result right way if no match was found, you could use `JoinWindows#before(...)` (or `#after(...)`) to define a "asymmetric" window. Cf the JavaDocs of `JoinWindows` for details.

For more details checkout https://www.confluent.io/events/kafka-summit-europe-2021/temporal-joins-in-kafka-streams-and-ksqldb/